# Set MultiIndex of an existing DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

I have a DataFrame that looks like

```
  Emp1    Empl2           date       Company
0    0        0     2012-05-01         apple
1    0        1     2012-05-29         apple
2    0        1     2013-05-02         apple
3    0        1     2013-11-22         apple
18   1        0     2011-09-09        google
19   1        0     2012-02-02        google
20   1        0     2012-11-26        google
21   1        0     2013-05-11        google
```

I want to pass the company and date for setting a `MultiIndex` for this DataFrame. Currently it has a default index. I am using

```py
df.set_index(['Company', 'date'], inplace=True)
```

But when I print, it prints `None`. Is this not the correct way of doing it? Also I want to shuffle the positions of the columns company and date so that company becomes the first index, and date becomes the second in Hierarchy. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Works for me no problem, what version pandas and numpy are you using? Can you post code and data to reproduce the issue

Comment: @ Andy Hayden : Before setting the index the df was printed in the way I have posted in my original question.

Comment: How is that a multi index? It looks like you set a normal 1 dimensional index.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

When you pass inplace in makes the changes on the original variable and returns None, and the function **does not** return the modified dataframe, it returns None.

```
is_none = df.set_index(['Company', 'date'], inplace=True)
df  # the dataframe you want
is_none # has the value None
```

so when you have a line like:

```
df = df.set_index(['Company', 'date'], inplace=True)
```

it first modifies `df`... but then it sets `df` to None!

That is, you should just use the line:

```
df.set_index(['Company', 'date'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

The result of `set_index()` is a copy, so you can assign it back to `df` (instead of using `inplace=` parameter).

```py
df = df.set_index(['Company', 'date'])
```

[image: res1]

Note how `set_index()` overwrites the old index by default. You can keep the old index by appending the new indices via the `append=` parameter.

```py
df = df.set_index(['Company', 'date'], append=True)
```

[image: res2]

The new index doesn't need to come from the columns. You can pass a pandas Series or a numpy array of the same length as the dataframe to `set_index()`.

```py
new_idx = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'])
df = df.set_index([new_idx, 'date'])
```

[image: res3]

To set a brand new MultiIndex, you can use `pd.MultiIndex` object. Depending on what you use to build the index, there are convenient methods, `from_arrays()`, `from_tuples()`, `from_product()`.

For example, if you want to create a MultiIndex from the Cartesian product of `lst1` and `lst2`, you can do so by calling `from_product()`. Note that the length of the MultiIndex must match the length of the dataframe for this to work.

```py
lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
lst2 = [100, 200]
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([lst1, lst2])
```

[image: res5]

Comment: Can I use `set_idex` to create a multiindex using tuples stores in one of the columns of the dataframe?  Or do I have to (1) construct and assign a multiindex using `pd.Multiindex.from_tuples()`; and then (2) drop the column from the dataframe?

Comment: @Confounded The column must be converted into a MultiIndex if you want to use it as a MultiIndex later, so your method is the correct way. You can also remove the column beforehand using `pop`. So something like `df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.pop('tup_col')))`.